# Not able to connect to host on port 8080 and 4848 from browser

Tags: linux, networking, centos, port

Glassfish is installed on remote Linux server (Centos).
Ports are open. checked by using command netstat.
im able to connect host using 'curl' and 'telnet' for mention ports(8080,4848) but not able to access from any browser.
nmap  command shows ports 8080,4848 status OPEN.
operating system : CentOS Linux 8 (Core)

what may be the issue?